# Kafka Connect is encoding data

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, kafka-producer-api

I have troubles when extracting data from DB using jdbc connector.

Some columns are number in Oracle but when extracting i got encoded values.

Here is an example:

```
col1            col2            col3            col4
100036061921    100049035196    100413362646    01
```

The result in my topic:

```
{
  "col1": "BWBMnkE5f1sHNOKvb77Ht0ihv+fIQftrys3Z/TBOajX4LboFATPyuEsbgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\u003d\u003d",
  "col2": "BWB6T7Z91Z/RUpevfd7yNAxnUF9YtFkFw/rJDw4aUDp1TIvXKANURhfLAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\u003d\u003d",
  "col3": "BWBNLeG3IR80rH4seAWU6C6V7K5IunlyVI2u+F7fuY362YtxbCLmrsohgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\u003d\u003d",
  "col4": "01"
}
```

Some one have any idea to fix this issue?

Many thanks.

Comment: Please provide column types of your table

Comment: @IskuskovAlexander col1 col2 col3 are all NUMBER(12)

Comment: Waht's about col4?

Comment: @IskuskovAlexander it's an VARCHAR2(2)

Comment: For more precisions I've already specified ```"numeric.mapping": "best_fit"``` in my connector config

Answer (score 2):

Just fixed my issue after some googling.

Some "Numeric" DATA TYPES in DB are not `best_fit` with Kafka Connect, so you have to specify some CAST to get the result needed.

Here is the reference:
https://gist.github.com/rmoff/7bb46a0b6d27982a5fb7a103bb7c95b9#file-oracle-md

This may help Oracle,MS SQL SERVER, Postgre, Mysql users.

BR,

Achraf